# DNS point to server on ISP and keep shared host too?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I know this is probably quite easy to do, but I might just have the right search sorted out... so here is the situation:

We have example.com set up as a hosted server along with app1.example.com, app2.example.com and a few others. What I would like to do is set up the right zone file to also make our internal server addressable from the outside world as internalapp.example.com.

This server sits behind a firewall (pfsense) and is hooked up to the world via a cable modem that is technically on DHCP from our ISP, but has had the same external IP for the past 15 months so far.

What would be the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you trust your ISP:

just add "A" record for example.com zone for internalapp.example.com. pointing to your external IP ([IP] A internalapp.example.com), and forward port (NAT, DMZ etc) 80/443 on your firewall to your internal server.

If you don't trust your ISP:

- (better way) make tunnel between pfsense and your hosted server and be sure that packets are transmitted with relevant IP's, without SNAT (this may lead to incorrect client address records in your logs, environment etc).
- (bad way) you need to update record dynamically, which is weird and even if your IP changes, clients will timeout according to DNS record timings set. example: DDNS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS